# The best known upper bound for two-way probabilistic finite automata with one-counter

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, automata-theory, upper-bounds

It is known that the class of languages recognized by two-way deterministic finite automata with one-counter (2D1CAs) is a proper subset of $ \mathsf{L} $ (deterministic log-space):
A 2D1CA can run at most $ O(n^2) $ steps if it halts on a given input, and there is a language in $ \mathsf{L} $, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\mathtt{DG} = \lbrace w_0 \$ w_1 \$ \cdots \$ w_k \mid k \geq 1, w_{i \in \lbrace 0, \ldots, k \rbrace} \in \lbrace a,b\rbrace^* , \mbox{ and }  w_0=w_i \mbox{ for some }  1 \leq  i  \leq k \rbrace,
\end{equation}
which cannot be recognized by any 2D1CA [(Duris and Galil, 1982)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397582900871).

What happens if such an automaton can use a coin?

More precisely, what is the best known upper bound for the class of languages recognized by two-way **probabilistic** finite automata with one-counter (2P1CAs) with bounded error?